# Can't deploy Spring Boot app on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am deploying simple Spring Boot app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. 
It seems pretty simple. 
I just created war-file and deployed it on Amazon.
However, I receives the following errors during creating the environment:

> Creating Auto Scaling group named:
>   awseb-e-5zxuiqb7jh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1JVXAWPWCK3FK failed.
>   Reason: You have requested more instances (1) than your current
>   instance limit of 0 allows for the specified instance type. Please
>   visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an
>   adjustment to this limit. Launching EC2 instance failed.
>
> Stack named 'awseb-e-5zxuiqb7jh-stack' aborted operation. Current
>   state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

Comment: What specifically is unclear with that error? You obviously have a limit of 0 instances for the instance type which you want to create. You have to increase the limit or choose another instance type.

Comment: Thank you. I followed standard registration. So why I have the limit of 0 instances? How can I increase this limit?

Comment: I don't have insight into your account. Have you clicked on the given link and sent a message to customer support?

Comment: You are right. I'll send a message to the support. Thanks.